# Add round egde to a map marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using a InfoWindowAdapter to add a custom infowindow to my marker.Everything is fine except for one thing, I cant find a way to have a round edge for my infowindow

I am using google mapV2.Any code snippet regarding this would be really helpfull

Comment: do u want to show info window with rounded corner or the point u place the marker want to show round?

Comment: @Pratik i want to show the info window with round corner

Comment: k wait i m going to post answer.

Comment: try my code...and let me know if it helps...somebody gave u -1..so try to post ur question as "How to show the info window with round corner?"and before delete question please inform me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
 gMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) 
        {
            View vMapInfo = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_info_layout, null);
            return vMapInfo;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) 
        {
            //View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_info_layout, null);
            return null;            

        }
    });
```

**map_info_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/bg_map_info"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
 >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_map_info"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMapStoreName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ivMapGo"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="test text test text test text test text "
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_common"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMapGo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMapStoreDistance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvMapStoreName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvMapStoreName"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="100 Miles"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

</RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

and the below is the XML of info window background.

**bg_map_info.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item> 
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#a0333333"
            android:endColor="#a0000000" />
        <corners 
            android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="5dp" 
            android:topRightRadius="5dp" />         

    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="20dp"> 
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#70000000"
            android:endColor="#70000000" />
        <corners 
            android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="5dp" 
            android:topRightRadius="5dp" />     </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: i tried your code but wat it does is that it shows a view with square edges and within that view it gives a round edged view.

Comment: @Abhilash try my edited answer.I have just changed android:background="#00ffffff" to android:background="@drawable/bg_map_info"

Comment: this makes the layout with rounded corners but hides the content. any idea why this happens?

Comment: @TharakaNirmana can u share ur layout if diff then my answer.

Comment: @Flash It is exactly the same as yours, except my one does not have an imageview. The issue is I can not see two textviews when the ui infowindow get rounded corners.

Comment: @TharakaNirmana hi I just checked its working..plz make width and height to wrap_content and give some padding to root layout.

Comment: @Flash I tried, still no luck. this is my code 
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
     
     public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
      View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customized_info_window, null);
      return v;
     }
     
     public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

info_window_layout
      View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customized_info_window, null);
title
      TextView heading = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.heading);
      heading.setText("Sample");
      return v;
     }
});

Comment: @TharakaNirmana plz put ur code in getInfoContents method and try.

Answer (score 0):

It works properly if you inflate your .xml file into the method- getInfoWindow(). This method allows you to provide a view that will be used for the entire info window.

Answer (score 0):

**CustomInfoWindowLayout:-**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/_10dp_">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="224dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_window_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:fontFamily="@font/yaldevi_medium"
            android:textColor="#454f63"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12sp_" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_window_lat_lng"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6dp_"
            android:fontFamily="@font/yaldevi_semi_bold"
            android:textColor="#454f63"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12sp_" />

       </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**btn_bg_white.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="#DAC9C9"
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/_8dp_" />
    </shape>
</item>
</ripple>
```

MapActivity.java:-

```
 mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
    @Nullable
    Override
    public View getInfoWindow(@NonNull Marker marker) {
    View myContentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
    R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
    TextView tvAddress = ((TextView) myContentView
    findViewById(R.id.info_window_address));
                
    tvAddress.setText(HelperMethods.getCompleteAddressString(MapsActivity.this, 
    marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude));
    TextView tvLatLng = ((TextView) myContentView
    findViewById(R.id.info_window_lat_lng));
                
    tvLatLng.setText(HelperMethods.convertDegMinsSecs(marker.getPosition().latitude, 
    marker.getPosition().longitude));
    return myContentView;
    }
l
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(@NonNull Marker marker) {

                return null;
            }
        });
```