# RelativeLayout width in a custom info window for API Maps v2

Tags: android, maps, android-relativelayout, android-maps-v2

I have a custom info window for Google Maps API v2 that uses a RelativeLayout added by overwritting getInfoWindow in my class. This layout has a TextView with a title in the first line and three TextViews in the next line, one aligned to the left, another to the center and the thrid one to the right. It works, but the window takes the whole of the screen, which is very ugly in big screens like tablets.

I have tried to set the width of the RelativeLayout to some fixed value (let's say "50dp") or to "wrap_content", but it always takes the whole of the screen.

This is the XML for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bus_stop_info_window"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffffff" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="A title" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Test1" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test2" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Test3" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I achieve the desired effect?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611425/add-round-egde-to-a-map-marker/17613299#17613299

Comment: Wrapping the RelativeLayout in a LinearLayout, following the idea your link, worked. Thank you very much! If you want to post the solution as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For that make root element as Linear-layout and put Relative-layout inside it.so that window will not fill the whole screen in tablet.This will not affect whether Relative-layout width is wrap_content or fixed size.

U can try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611425/add-round-egde-to-a-map-marker/17613299#17613299)

Comment: what about in normal device?

Comment: I can confirm that this approach works, but why the layout is broken when using `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` as a parent? Is it another Google's bug?